# What's the difference between using boost::equality_comparable<T> versus overriding bool operator ==?

Tags: c++, boost

When would I use boost::equality_comparable vs overriding T's `bool operator==(T const& rhs)` method?

Here's some sample code.

```cpp
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

enum class AnEnum : uint64_t;

struct Base : boost::equality_comparable<Base> {
    std::shared_ptr<AnEnum > units;

    std::shared_ptr<int> value;

    bool operator ==(Base const& rhs) { 
        return (*value == *rhs.value)
            && (*units == *rhs.units); 
    }

    friend bool operator == (const Base & lhs, const Base & rhs) {
        return (*lhs.value == *rhs.value)
            && (*lhs.units == *rhs.units);
    };
};
```

I was hoping Boost would auto implement operator == but the compiler complained about a missing implementation error. Why would I want to use boost::equality_comparable when I have to implement it anyways?

Comment: Well according to this doc page http://stir.sourceforge.net/documentation/doxy/html/structboost_1_1equality__comparable.html equality_comparable is used to define the != not the == operator.

Comment: True, I changed it to    `struct Base : boost::equality_comparable<Base, Base>` and am still getting the error. (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#arithmetic , for reference)

Comment: Function operator == is still not autogenerated when i made `struct Base : boost::equivalent<Base>`

Comment: It is used to automatically generate the != operator when you have already defined the == operator.  No longer needed in C++20

Comment: How do I automatically generate the == operator?