# How do I automatically generate the == operator with boost/operators.hpp?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Follow up from this since I am asking a slightly different question: 
[What's the difference between using boost::equality_comparable<T> versus overriding bool operator ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243286/whats-the-difference-between-using-boostequality-comparablet-versus-overrid?noredirect=1#comment102860555_58243286)

Here's my attempt of doing it code.

```cpp
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

enum class AnEnum : uint64_t;

struct Base : boost::equality_comparable<Base, Base> {
    std::shared_ptr<AnEnum > units;

    std::shared_ptr<int> value;

    bool operator ==(Base const& rhs) { 
        return (*value == *rhs.value)
            && (*units == *rhs.units); 
    }

    friend bool operator == (const Base & lhs, const Base & rhs) {
        return (*lhs.value == *rhs.value)
            && (*lhs.units == *rhs.units);
    };
};
```

I was hoping Boost would auto implement operator == but the compiler complained about a missing implementation error. How do I automatically implement the following function:

`bool operator == (const Base & lhs, const Base & rhs);`

I am using this as a reference: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#arithmetic

EDIT:

How do I get the == operator to be automatically defined, as per the following:

```cpp
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

enum class AnEnum : uint64_t;

struct Base : boost::equality_comparable<Base, Base> {
    std::shared_ptr<AnEnum > units;

    std::shared_ptr<int> value;

    friend bool operator == (const Base & lhs, const Base & rhs);
};
```

Comment: I don't know how you tested, but it works form me, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8b2a94a7b2473fc)

Comment: PS: are you sure that you want to share units and value ..

Comment: You already define the same operator twice.  Why do you want to define it a third time?  You should remove the first definition.

Comment: I am not trying to define 3 operators.  I want to automatically generate 1 == operator , see edit.

Comment: >PS: are you sure that you want to share units and value

Why not?

Comment: You will not get `operator==` automatically defined. Computers are not yet at the point where they can read your mind and write code for you. Which is a good thing, or we'd all be out of jobs.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::equality_comparable<T>` expects `T` to provide `operator==`, and provides `operator!=` based on that. It does not somehow magically know how to compare arbitrary classes. It's right there [in the reference you cite](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#equality_comparable1) - note what's in Requirements column and in Supplied Operations column.

`boost::equality_comparable<Base, Base>` is kind of pointless. Two-parameter form of `equality_comparable` is designed to synthesize heterogeneous comparisons, between objects of different types.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically generate the implementation for the header : `bool operator == (const Base & lhs, const Base & rhs);` ?

Comment: Why would you want both a member and a non-member version of `operator==`? It doesn't make sense to provide both - if you do, any attempt to actually compare two instances would produce an "ambiguous overload" error. Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Also, you want the member version of `operator==` to be `const`, as in `bool operator ==(const Base& rhs) const;`

Comment: >Why would you want both a member and a non-member version of operator==? 

See Edit, I am not trying to provide both. 

Also what does the const do?

Comment: `const` makes the member function callable on a const object. As in `const Base a, b; if (a == b) ...` Without `const` this won't compile.

Comment: Swift 'reads my mind' for this specific feature - https://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-get-equatable-and-hashable-for-free/ . Relevant section: `You only need to tell the compiler that you want this type to be Equatable by declaring conformance to the protocol:` I now realize that C++ does not have this luxury.

Comment: For complex objects, it probably makes sense to implement a custom function however, in my opinion, I think there should be a naive solution baked into the language. Naive in this case is automatically comparing primitives and enums and recursively checking equality of sub-objects that have primitives and enums

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is neither a primitive nor an enum, but an object of class type. Further, this class does provide `operator==` which does **not** do what you seem to expect (it compares the two raw pointers, not the pointed-to objects). So your hypothetical Equatable may not work very well in your example.